# Check if records exists at least once in LEFT JOINED Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an Images, Orders and OrderItems table, I want to match for any images, if any has already been bought by the User passed as parameters by displaying *true* or *false* in an **IsBought** column.

```
Select  Images.Id, 
        Images.Title, 
        Images.Description, 
        Images.Location, 
        Images.PriceIT, 
        Images.PostedAt,
        CASE WHEN OrderItems.ImageId = Images.Id THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) 
             ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END 
        AS 'IsBought'    
FROM Images
INNER JOIN Users as u on Images.UserId = u.Id

LEFT JOIN Orders on  Orders.UserId = @userId
LEFT JOIN OrderItems on Orders.Id = OrderItems.OrderId and  OrderItems.ImageId = Images.Id

Group By Images.Id, 
            Images.Title, 
            Images.Description, 
            Images.Location, 
            Images.PriceIT, 
            Images.PostedAt,
            OrderItems.ImageId,
            Orders.UserId
```

When I use this CASE WHEN I have duplicates when the item has been bought where **IsBought** is *True* and the duplicate is *False*.
In the case where the Item has never been bought, there is no duplicates, **IsBought** is just equal to *False*

```
----------------------------------
| User       |  type             |
----------------------------------
| Id         | nvarchar(450)     |
----------------------------------
| .......|
----------------------------------

----------------------------------
| Orders     |  type             |
----------------------------------
| Id         | nvarchar(255)     |
----------------------------------
| UserId     | nvarchar(450)     |
----------------------------------
| ...........................    |
----------------------------------

----------------------------------
| OrderItems |  type             |
----------------------------------
| Id         | nvarchar(255)     |
----------------------------------
| OrderId     | nvarchar(255)    |
----------------------------------
| ImageId    | int               |
----------------------------------

----------------------------------
| Images     |  type             |
----------------------------------
| Id         | int               |
----------------------------------
| UserId     | nvarchar(450)     |
----------------------------------
| Title      | nvarchar(MAX)      |
----------------------------------
| Description| nvarhar(MAX)      |
----------------------------------
| .........................      |
----------------------------------
```

Any ideas on how I could just have one row per Images with **IsBought** set to true or false but not duplicates?

I would like something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id   |  Title  | Description | Location | PriceIT |  Location | IsBought | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |  Eiffel Tower  | .... | ...... | 20.0      |  Paris     | true    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |  Tore di Pisa  | .... | ...... | 20.0      |  Italia     | false  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| etc ......
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and desired output. [mcve]

Comment: I added some details about the tables structure and the desired output ..

Comment: What is the point of using a group by here? You don't have any aggregation.

Comment: My bad, in the original request I have some aggregations.. can be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query logic looks suspicious. It is unusual to see a join that consists only of a comparison of a column from the unpreserved table to a parameter. I suspect that you don't need a join to users at all since you seem to be focused on things "bought" by a person and not things "created" (which is implied by the name "author") by that same person. And a group by clause with no aggregate is often a cover-up for a logically flawed query.

So start over. You want to see all images apparently. For each, you simply want to know if that image is associated with any order of a given person.

```
select img.*, -- you would, or course, only select the columns needed 

   (select count(*) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as orddet 
    where orddet.ProductID = img.ProductID) as [Order Count],

   (select count(*) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as orddet 
    inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader as ord 
       on orddet.SalesOrderID = ord.SalesOrderID
    where orddet.ProductID = img.ProductID
    and ord.CustomerID = 29620
    ) as [User Order Count], 

    case when exists(select * from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as orddet 
    inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader as ord 
       on orddet.SalesOrderID = ord.SalesOrderID
    where orddet.ProductID = img.ProductID
    and ord.CustomerID = 29620) then 1 else 0 end as [Has Ordered] 

from Production.ProductProductPhoto as img 
where img.ProductID between 770 and 779
order by <something useful>;
```

Notice the aliases - it is much easier to read a long query when you use aliases that are shorter but still understandable (i.e., not single letters). I've included 3 different subqueries to help you understand correlation and how you can build your logic to achieve your goal and help debug any issues you find.

This is based on AdventureWorks sample database - which you should install and use as a learning tool (and to help facilitate discussions with others using a common data source). Note that I simply picked a random customer ID value - you would use your parameter. I filtered the query to a range of images to simplify debugging. Those are very simple but effective methods to help write and debug sql.

Comment: Thank you, your example really helped me understanding my errors and fix my issue.
I remove the LEFT JOIN From Orders and OrderItems tables and put your CASE WHEN EXISTS. It worked!